Loading 6000 items in combo box
I need to load 6000+ searchable items as combobox dropdown selection items, but all of the approaches I have used do not work.
Power Apps has a 2000 item limit for delegable data sources, but I need to load 6000+ items from a spreadsheet on a SharePoint page. I tried to load the static data to get around the delegating limit, but when I filter the data to narrow the possible items (one of the design specs I must follow) it shows no results. After trying several attempts I determined that anything I try to do that doesn't use the static data as is malfunctions.
Then, I tried to use a collection by loading 2000 items in at a time, but I was not able to make this work either.

There is no reason to have a 6000+ item combo box. There is a better data structure out there for what you need to do.

have a search dialog and show the matches in a combo box, if the user selects any - post them into a separate 'selected' box (allow them to remove items from there)
